# How do I create a branch without cloning?

Tags: git, git-branch

I'd like to automate the creation of feature branches that match in multiple projects. I can script this but to speed things up it would be nice if I could just tell the remote repo to create the branch, without cloning the entire source code. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your remote repo isn't bare, then you can do all this using ssh and running the git commands directly on your remote repository.  The syntax for ssh is pretty simple: `ssh user@host command`:

```
ssh dev1@remotebox git branch newbranchname
ssh dev2@remotebox git checkout newbranchname
ssh jenkinsci@remotebox git pull --quiet --no-commit
```

And so on.

If your remote repo is bare or if you cannot ssh to the remote repository, then no, you can't do this.  The git transfer protocol doesn't permit it.  As far as I know, the only commands you can run on remote repositories without a local clone all have the "-remote" suffix.  `ls-remote`, `peek-remote` and `parse-remote`.

Comment: Great, what would be the git commands then? Something like
git init ?
git fetch origin
git branch blah blah

Comment: Any git commands that you can run in a non-bare repository.  With ssh, you're actually on the remote machine when you run the command.  I've updated my answer with some trivial examples.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your comment. It sounds like you're saying to ssh into the server the remote repo is on? The context of this is I'm using Jenkins and GitHub. Not sure I could remote in. If I have a branch name and a commit hash for each repo, I am hoping I can tell the remote repo to make a branch from the commit without cloning locally.

Comment: You cannot do that without a local repository.  Your solutions are either to go to the remote machine (thereby making it the local repository, temporarily), or cloning it.  I'll rephrase my answer.

Comment: @marty You can just use the GitHub API http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#create-a-reference

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks like the GitHub API will be the way to go.